# Issue with special characters not appearing when upload .csv file even though encoding is correct UTF-8

Tags: c#, csv

Here is my situation and I have not found an answer for this in any post I've looked at.  The app I am working on allows the user to select a .csv file to upload, but Spanish and Portuguese characters such as á,é,ñ and õ appear as a black diamond with a '?' in it.  Now, I verified that the .csv file was saved in UTF-8 format, but when the follow code fragment is executed:

```
using (StreamReader objStreamReader = new StreamReader(p_strFilename, Encoding.UTF8))
{
     string strLine;
     while ((strLine = objStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null && lstErrors.Count <= _MAX_ERRORS)
```

strLine contains the black diamonds with a '?' where the special characters should be after ReadLine() is executed.  Note that my .csv file has been verified as UTF-8 and the StreamReader is expecting UTF-8.  Therfore, why aren't the special characters appearing correctly?  If anyone has insight into this your answers will be much appreciated.

Thanks.
Jim B.

Comment: When you say that those characters appear as black diamonds, what program are you viewing them in? Have you opened the file in Notepad? Visual Studio? Displaying it on the console? It's quite possible that the file is okay but the program you're displaying it with can't display those characters.

Comment: I was viewing it in debug mode in Visual Studio 2010.  I should add that this is the same way it is appearing to our users on the aspx page.

Comment: So you are then pretty convinced that the file actually **contains** those characters.  You'll need to look at the app that created this file.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your users are experiencing difficulties with the Character Encoding on the aspx page. By default, the local browser uses the local character set (makes sense, right?). If your source data makes use of a different character set/encoding, you may want to add a meta tag to the page so that the browser displays the data correctly. From the Microsoft page: [Globalization Step-by-Step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688114.aspx):

> <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=">
>   You substitute with any supported character-set-friendly name (for example, UTF-8) or any code-page name (for example, windows 1251).

Some other good places to look for more information on this topic are:

[Globalization issues in ASP and ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893663)
[Setting the HTTP charset parameter](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset.en.php)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like good info.  But, I think, as said in my original message, that the issue is happening before it gets to the aspx page.  The output to this line [ strLine = objStreamReader.ReadLine() ] in the code behind during debugging is showing the the black diamonds with a '?'